# How to stop while loop by click on button in streamlit

Tags: python-3.x, streamlit

I am trying to build an UI where by clicking on a button recording gets started. and when click on a button ("Stop Recording") the recording should stop.
I am doing the operation right now with a while loop and recorder.
The concern is that when the while loop is running and I am clicking on "Stop Recording" button the loop is not stopping.

I have written the code like this.

```
with col1:
if st.button('Record Audio'):
    st.write('Recording starts')
    recorder.start()
    while Record_stop == 0:
        frame = recorder.read()
        audio.extend(frame)
        print('Recording')
        
with col2:
    if st.button('Stop Recording'):
        Record_stop = 1
        recorder.stop()
        st.write('Recording stopped')
        Record_stop = 0
```

Can anyone suggest the solution to stop the loop by button click.
I might be missing some basic python rules here, But would be helpful if someone can help here.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Try integrating streamlit's session state here.

```
with col1:
  if st.button('Record Audio'):
    st.write('Recording starts')
    recorder.start()
    st.session_state['recording'] = True
    while st.session_state['recording']== True:
        frame = recorder.read()
        audio.extend(frame)
        st.write('Recording')
        
with col2:
    if st.button('Stop Recording'):
        recorder.stop()
        st.write('Recording stopped')
        st.session_state['recording'] = False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use session state just like Dorecahl's answer or you can use experimental_rerun to force the while loop to stop.
This should work.

```
with col1:
if st.button('Record Audio'):
    st.write('Recording starts')
    recorder.start()
    while Record_stop == 0:
        frame = recorder.read()
        audio.extend(frame)
        print('Recording')
        
with col2:
    if st.button('Stop Recording'):
        Record_stop = 1
        st.experimental_rerun()
        recorder.stop()
        st.write('Recording stopped')
        Record_stop = 0
```